# CRC of input data shorter than poly width

Tags: vba, crc

I'm in the process of writing a paper during my studies on implementing CRC in Excel with VBA.
I've created a fairly straightforward, modular algorithm that uses Ross's [parametrized model](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt).
It works flawlessly for any length polynomian and any combination of parameters except for one; when the length of the input data is shorter than the width of the polynomial **and** an initial value is chosen ("INIT") that has any bits set which are "past" the length of the input data.

Example:

```
Input Data: 0x4C
Poly: 0x1021
Xorout: 0x0000
Refin: False
Refout: False
```

If I choose no INIT or any INIT like 0x##00, I get the same checksum as any of the online CRC generators. If any bit of the last two hex characters is set - like 0x0001 - my result is invalid.

I believe the question boils down to "How is the register initialized if only one byte of input data is present for a two byte INIT parameter?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was misled (or I very well may have misinterpreted) the explaination of how to use the INIT parameter on the [sunshine2k](http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/crc/understanding_crc.html#ch86) website.
The INIT value must not be XORed with the first *n* input bytes per se (*n* being the width of the register / cropped poly / checksum), but must only be XORed in after the *n* 0-Bits have been appended to the input data.
This specification does not matter when input data is equal or larger than *n* bytes, but it does matter when the input data is too short.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was. The example code in the Ross link initializes the CRC, then it updates the CRC one byte at a time (not `n` bits at a time) which shouldn't be an issue. After calculating the CRC, it's appended to the input data (effectively xor'ed with `n` appended 0 bits), normally most significant byte first. You didn't post the failing code, so I can't be sure what the problem was.

Comment: I had built my own code since I'm doing a VBA implementation in Excel. Because of that, my algorithm works fairly step-by-step.
Judging from what I read on the sunshine2k website, I had assumed you had to simply XOR the initialisor into the input data, and then go along the oridinary path (append 0 bits, fill register with input data, calculate CRC from there on). I wasn't sure where to XOR the initialisor into since the input data was _too short_. It now works as intended when I append the 0 bits before XORing in the initial value - having enough material to XOR with.